# Encode pandas column as categorical values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follow:

```
d = {'item': [1, 2,3,4,5,6], 'time': [1297468800, 1297468809, 12974688010, 1297468890, 1297468820,1297468805]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

the output of `df` is as follow:

```
   item         time
0     1   1297468800
1     2   1297468809
2     3   1297468801
3     4   1297468890
4     5   1297468820
5     6   1297468805
```

the `time` here is based on the unixsystem time. My goal is to replace the `time` column in the dataframe.

such as the

```
mintime = 1297468800
maxtime = 1297468890
```

And I want to split the time into `10` (can be changed by using parameter like 20 intervals) interval, and recode the `time` column in `df`. Such as

```
   item         time
0     1          1
1     2          1
2     3          1
3     4          9
4     5          3
5     6          1
```

what is the most efficient way to do this since I have billion of records? Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain "And I want to split the time into 10 (can be changed by using parameter like 20 intervals) interval, and recode the time column in df" ? It does not make much sense. Can you walk us through the output here?

Comment: Sure, the whole time is `[mintime, maxtime]`, and I want to split this time interval into `10` time slots. like if `mintime=0, maxtime=10`. then we have (0,1], (1,2],(2,3],....(9,10]. In this case, time is enocoded by the continue unix system. And I want to split them into only several intervals.

Comment: Thanks. By my calculations, it seems like the second last output should be 3, not 2. Can you check it please?

Comment: I will correct it. thanks

Comment: I have given you options on how to get both outputs. It depends on how you treat the intervals. Ask if you need any more explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pd.cut` with `np.linspace` to specify the bins. This encodes your column categorically, from which you can then extract the codes in order:

```
bins = np.linspace(df.time.min() - 1, df.time.max(), 10)
df['time'] = pd.cut(df.time, bins=bins, right=True).cat.codes + 1
df

   item  time
0     1     1
1     2     1
2     3     1
3     4     9
4     5     3
5     6     1
```

---

Alternatively, depending on how you treat the interval edges, you could also do

```
bins = np.linspace(df.time.min(), df.time.max() + 1, 10)
pd.cut(df.time, bins=bins, right=False).cat.codes + 1

0    1
1    1
2    1
3    9
4    2
5    1
dtype: int8
```